# Best way to provide ajax status updates with django / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have developed a django view that takes about 3 minutes to run. The view is called through a jquery ajax GET call, and eventually returns a response in JSON.

I would like to provide the user status updates as the django view processes the request.

For example (Processed 8/200 records...)

I could fetch each record with an individual ajax request, but it seems awfully cumbersome to make 200 requests to the server instead of just one.

Is there any way to have django 'ping' back status updates, without returning a full response?

Comment: maybe this will help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#streaminghttpresponse-objects

Comment: consider maintaining a table with "process_id" and "records_processed" columns. Start the process with one ajax call and leave it running. with another ajax call, you can check the status as many or less as you want. and the main process can update your table with the status of your process.